# How do I move the terminal in Geany?

Tags: geany

Is there any way we can move the terminal from the bottom to the sidebar?

We work in ROR and the terminal is used quite often, so having them side by side would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

From the Geany menu bar:

Edit → Preferences → Interface → Message Window Position: Right (Default: Bottom)